# How to extract data from a JSON tye column which field name has special characters?

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery, feature-extraction

I have the following JSON type column in a Bigquery table. I've been able to extract several columns from this JSON type column using JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(column_name,"$.field_name"), but when I tried to do the same thing whit the field named &&products, I retrive the following output.

> **Invalid token in JSONPath at: .&&products**

Here is an example of the JSON:

````json
{"page_siteSection":"Juguetería","page_pageType":"product list page","page_loginStatus":"guest","showPlp":"1","page_canal":"app","page_appSection":"showPlp","page":"plp","page_number":"1","page_previousPageName":"MAPPING_NOT_FOUND","page_pageName":"plp: Juguetería","sku_list":"882696728,882575700,882401880,882008929,882583634,881893746,881646404,881629066,882583930,882133550,882135129,882564681,881969441,881663405,882643810,882647787,881956442,882568189,882647793,882557468,882564687,881962673,882561842,882561846,113342573,114320584,16765239,18722548,114270995,114271159,114413499,114413451,18977742,19097731,114320991,17957150,19453119,19388261,19378246,19140238,19091371,19388285,18017648,19388276,19254877,19182189,114271264,113373122","hometag":"V-DY|Vitrina|1|x|2|null|product list page|HO_V2_JUG_1389|https:\/\/\/v3\/assets\/bltf4ed0b9a176c126e\/bltc490f6289eb561f9\/6387d247fa61d3109a1043de\/2-vitrina-w49-juguetería-app-av_v2.png","page_sessionId":"","sis_experience":"olo","&&products":";882696728;;;;position={1},;882575700;;;;position={2},;882401880;;;;position={3},;882008929;;;;position={4},;882583634;;;;position={5},;881893746;;;;position={6},;881646404;;;;position={7},;881629066;;;;position={8},;882583930;;;;position={9},;882133550;;;;position={10},;882135129;;;;position={11},;882564681;;;;position={12},;881969441;;;;position={13},;881663405;;;;position={14},;882643810;;;;position={15},;882647787;;;;position={16},;881956442;;;;position={17},;882568189;;;;position={18},;882647793;;;;position={19},;882557468;;;;position={20},;882564687;;;;position={21},;881962673;;;;position={22},;882561842;;;;position={23},;882561846;;;;position={24},;113342573;;;;position={25},;114320584;;;;position={26},;16765239;;;;position={27},;18722548;;;;position={28},;114270995;;;;position={29},;114271159;;;;position={30},;114413499;;;;position={31},;114413451;;;;position={32},;18977742;;;;position={33},;19097731;;;;position={34},;114320991;;;;position={35},;17957150;;;;position={36},;19453119;;;;position={37},;19388261;;;;position={38},;19378246;;;;position={39},;19140238;;;;position={40},;19091371;;;;position={41},;19388285;;;;position={42},;18017648;;;;position={43},;19388276;;;;position={44},;19254877;;;;position={45},;19182189;;;;position={46},;114271264;;;;position={47},;113373122;;;;position={48}"}```


Since I've been able to extract fields such as page_section and others, when I use JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(column_name,"$.&&products") it does not work for me and shows the above error. Any hints?
````

Comment: The above Json is not Valid You can check the above Json in JsonFormatter online . Check Json first is the Json is Valid or not .Then try to extract records from that Json using JSON_QUERY or JSON_VALUE

Comment: this might be helpful.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69566019/how-to-get-a-value-of-key-with-thru-json-extract-in-bigquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work since it is not a valid JSONPath.

I guess the only option you have is to take that JSON field as a STRING, perform some replace operations to adjust the JSON to the standard rules and then CAST it again to JSON and perform your JSON Path queries.